# Default-Start contains no runlevels

Tags: debian, services, init-script, sysvinit

I am trying to make my custom made daemon run at startup
and when I call
`update-rc.d ydcd enable`

I get the error

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: MyDaemon Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

I'm running Debian wheezy, init is SysVinit.

Googling it does not give me any valuable info, so I come here as a last resort.

What's going on here?
What do I need to change in my init.d script in order to make this work?

Edit:

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#ydcd.daemon
#
# chkconfig: 2345 85 15
# description: MyServiceName
# processname: MyServiceName
# source function library

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

RETVAL=0
NAME=ydcd.daemon
# YOU CAN SET ANY PATH BUT IS RECOMENDED TO USE THE DISTRO'S STANDARD ONE.
DAEMON=/home/debian/yd_cd/$NAME
prog=$(basename $DAEMON)
lockfile=/var/lock/$NAM

SVC_FILE=$DAEMON
start() {
    if [ -f $SVC_FILE ]; then
      #reset
      echo -n "Starting "$SVC_FILE": "
      RETVALS=$(start-stop-daemon -S -b -x $SVC_FILE -- -r)

          Count=${#RETVALS[@]}
      RETVAL="[FAIL]"

          if [ $Count -eq 0 ]; then
        RETVAL="[OK]"
      elif [ $Count -eq 1 ]; then
        if [ ${#RETVALS[0]} -eq 0 ]; then
          RETVAL="[OK]"
        else
          iStart=${#SVC_FILE}
          iLength=${#RETVALS[0]}
          Response=${RETVALS[0]:(iStart+1):7}
          RETVAL=$Response
          if [ "$Response" == "already" ]; then
            RETVAL="[OK]"
          fi
        fi
      fi
      echo $RETVAL
          return 0
    else
      echo $SVC_ALIAS" not installed" $SVC_DIR
      exit 2;
    fi
}

stop() {
    echo -n "Shutting down "$SVC_FILE":"
    RETVALS=$(start-stop-daemon -K -x $SVC_FILE -- s)
    #additional PROCKILLS=$(killall -w -q -e $SVC_PROCESS_NAME $SVC_FILENAME)
    Count=${#RETVALS[@]}
    Index=0
    RETVAL="[FAIL]"
    if [ $Count -eq 1 ]; then
        if [ ${#RETVALS[0]} -eq 0 ]; then
            RETVAL="[OK]"
        else
            Response=${RETVALS[0]:0:2}
            RETVAL=$Response
            if [ "$Response" == "No" ]; then
                RETVAL="[OK]"
            fi
        fi
    else
        RETVAL="[OK]"
    fi

    echo $RETVAL
        return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status $SVC_SERVICE_SCRIPT
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
    echo $SVC_ALIAS" [Invalid Startup Parameters]"
    echo "Usage:  {start|stop|status|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Comment: You need to create the init script header, as shown here: https://serverfault.com/a/839081

Answer (score 0):

Debian is using systemd now by default, and that has no "runlevels". Legacy commands like the one you use *should* work, for some value of "work".

Answer (score 0):

You have the old-style `chkconfig` comment block at the beginning of your script.

Even though you use SysVinit, the modern init script management system is dependency-based: it needs to be told which other services your service depends on. This requires a newer-style LSB-compliant comment block, described in `man 5 init-d-script`:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ydcd.daemon
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: brief one-line description
# Description:       A more verbose description of your service
#                    possibly on multiple lines.
### END INIT INFO
```

This allows automatic ordering of the startup scripts, and also allows the system to run multiple startup scripts in parallel whenever dependencies allow. Just this has potential to speed up the system boot process by quite a lot - not quite as much as switching to a true dependency-based init system, but not an insignificant amount either.